# How to generate code (.ts) using serenity code generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a new project, I have also created model and all file as shown in the serenity sample project. I have updated the connection string with my local db. I have some doubts,

1. How to generate code type scripts(.ts) for the model and classes using serenity?
2. Do we need to create tables manually or using serenity can we create ?
3. How can we perform CRUD operations using serenity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer. We can scaffold the model and type scripts from tables itself. I think better way, do table design first after that we can scaffold the files using serenity code generator.

The serenity code generator can be open

```
open 'Package Manager Console'
```

(View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console) and type:
    sergen

after opening Serenity code generator we can select the tables that we need to scaffold. After scaffolding we have to rebuild our solution before running. Then we need to run the custom tool,

```
Right click on the "serverTyping.tt"  file and click on Run Custom Tool.
```

Hope this will help you.